# Compact set in the weak star topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $M_+(\mathbb R^+)$ be the space of the positive Radon measures.
Is the set
$$ A:= \left\{ \mu \in M_+(\mathbb R^+): \int_0^\infty x \mu(dx) \leq C \right\}$$
compact in the weak star topology?
What I was trying to do is to try to use the fact that balls are compact in the weak star topology, but I am not able to conclude that the set $A$ is compact.

Comment: Hint: Look at $\mu_n=c_n \delta_{1/n}$ with appropriate weights $c_n$.

Comment: Then $c_n$ could be such that $c_n = n C $ and therefore A is  not  bounded ? But does this implies non compactness?

Comment: Every weak$^\ast$ convergent sequence is norm bounded by the uniform boundedness principle.